# SQL proble with join condition

Tags: sql, count, isnull

I have a data base  like here

[image: data base shema]

I need to create a request to list the number of product available by product category.

However i should not list the product category without products.

We want at the end only column  CATEGORY_NAME (product_category.name) and PRODUCT_COUNT
Example of result :

```
---------------------------------
| CATEGORY_NAME | PRODUCT_COUNT |
---------------------------------
| Books         | 3 |
| Automotive    | 2 |
| High-tech     | 8 |
--------------------------------
```

I try this request but it's not good:

```
SELECT name AS CATEGORY_NAME, COUNT(available_stock) AS PRODUCT_COUNT
 FROM product
 GROUP BY name
 WHERE available_stock IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: You need to join to PRODUCT_CATEGORY and use the NAME column from that table.

Comment: thanks you i will try!